# Sql server Procedure Output convert to CSV File in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

Please provide me a dll or a way to convert Sql stored procedure output(Contains huge records nearly 10lakhs) into a CSV file in asp.net windows service.Thanks in advance

Comment: Google is your friend. We are not going to write the code for you

Answer (score 0):

```
protected void btnExportCSV_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Response.Clear();
    Response.Buffer = true;
    Response.AddHeader("content-disposition",
     "attachment;filename=GridViewExport.csv");
    Response.Charset = "";
    Response.ContentType = "application/text";

    GridView1.AllowPaging = false;
    GridView1.DataBind();

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (int k = 0; k < GridView1.Columns.Count; k++)
    {
        //add separator
        sb.Append(GridView1.Columns[k].HeaderText + ',');
    }
    //append new line
    sb.Append("\r\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < GridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        for (int k = 0; k < GridView1.Columns.Count; k++)
        {
            //add separator
            sb.Append(GridView1.Rows[i].Cells[k].Text + ',');
        }
        //append new line
        sb.Append("\r\n");
    }
    Response.Output.Write(sb.ToString());
    Response.Flush();
    Response.End();
}
```

Refer the above code

kindly see the below link

http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Export-GridView-To-Word-Excel-PDF-CSV-Formats-in-ASP.Net.aspx